# How to check if a word is present in url after # after nginx proxy pass

Tags: nginx, anchor, proxypass, nginx-reverse-proxy

I have an application setup in which nginx proxy pass is used. So an application is running on http://localhost:6700 So below is my nginx configuration

```
location /myapp {
    rewrite /myapp/(.*)$ /$1 break;
    ...
    ...
    proxy_pass http://localhost:6700;
    ...
}
```

Now my url is of form https://www.zeroapp.com:17882/myapp and app changes url to https://www.zeroapp.com:17882/myapp/app/myapp#/.../.../.../abc/...
So further if say a certain word "abc" is in url than i want to block all the urls using nginx that doesn't includes word abc after proxy pass i.e returned url.

Please advise on ways to achieve this

Thank you in advance
Sam

Comment: The `#` and anything following is the fragment, and is not part of the URL sent to the server. It is intended for and can only be processed client-side.

Comment: Thank you so much @RichardSmith for your comment and formatting my question. It is not possible to handle it on client side due to some application constraints. If you can suggest an possible alternative using nginx on server side that will be really helpful.

Comment: Is there a way if I can use sub_filter for this?